# Spring Kafka Integration for Kafka 0.9

Tags: spring-integration

Does Spring Kafka Integration support Kafka 0.9 ? From the Spring docs I could see that Spring Kafka Integration 1.3.0 was released to support Kafka 0.8 but for 0.9 there is a separate new project created called Spring-Kafka which will be used by Spring Kafka Integration 2.0, which is still in development.

Can I still use spring-kafka-integration 1.3.0 and would it support Kafka 0.9 ? would it help me to migrate to spring-kafka-integration 2.0 once its released ? Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your attention to those projects, first of all!

1. Spring Integration Kafka 1.x is exactly for Apache Kafka < 0.9. For 0.8.x to be strict.
2. Spring Kafka 1.0 (currently in the M1) is exactly for Kafka-0.9. And we hope that we will be compatible with Kafka 0.10 and beyond there.
3. With that in mind Spring Integration Kafka 2.0 is based on the Spring Kafka project and isn't compatible with the Apache Kafka < 0.9.
4. Kafka Client 0.8 (and therefore Spring Integration Kafka 1.x) is compatible with Kafka 0.9. So, you can use SIK-1.3 on the matter and migrate to SIK-2.0 when it will be ready.

Hope that helps.